# Is the expected value $\mu$ in the WLLN a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Am I right in thinking that the weak law of large numbers, when stating that
$$\bar{X_n} \to \mu$$
in probability convergence is stating that the sequence of  random variables $\{X_n\}$ tends to the **random variable** (as opposed to the real number) $M = \mu$, that is $M(\omega) = \mu \ \ \forall \omega$, and $p_M(\mu) = 1, \ p_M(x \neq \mu) = 0$?

The reason I ask is because in all the statements of the law I've seen it simply states that it tends to the expected value $\mu$, and I think convergence in probability is only defined as convergence of sequences of RVs to RVs. It's a subtle and rather unimportant distinction but I want to make sure I have the concepts right. Thanks!

Comment: Any constant is a random variable, so convergence in probability is defined when the random variables involved are constant.

Comment: A constant is not a random variable. A random variable is a function from $\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$. Of course we can define $M = \mu$, but by that we mean $M(\omega)=\mu \ \forall \omega \in \Omega$. I know the distincion is not conceptually important. I am new to the law of large numbers so I wanted to make sure I understood what is meant, formally.

Comment: In any case, "$\bar{X}_n\to\mu$ in probability" can't mean anything else than $\bar{X}_n$ tending in probability to the constant random variable $\omega\mapsto \mu$.